# Performance testing a cached API

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

I was wondering if anyone can educate me on an area of perf testing an API. I have an API which caches all its operations for extensive periods let's say a day. Based on this I felt there was no need to perf test the API as I would be testing infrastructure, configuration and http caching. Am I correct in my thinking? I am eager to know peoples opinions and any useful docs and papers would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Cache should be load-tested too, just to know your system's overall capacity (yes, most load goes to infrastructure, but at least you'll know that it does actually cache)

Second, but not by priority - you have the cache-miss branch and its capacity, if there's lot of cache misses - cache will not save your app, it still has to perform.